# Adding class via js

Tags: javascript, css, class

I have checked some questions about the same thing, but they didnt help me. Here is my code, what is wrong here? It does properly add the class, but not show changes at website.

```
//html
<div class="days"></div>

        //css
        .AddedClass {
        background-color: #27ae60;
        color: #fff;
        }

        //js
    let today = new Date();
    let endDate = new Date(
                dt.getFullYear(),
                dt.getMonth() + 1,
                0
            ).getDate();

    let cells = "";
    for (let i = 1; i <= endDate; i++) {
                if (!(i === today.getDate() && dt.getMonth() === today.getMonth() && dt.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear())) {
                    cells += `<div onclick='dayChanger(this);' data-value='${i}'>${i}</div>`;
                } else {
                    cells += `<div class='today' onclick='dayChanger(this);' data-value='${i}'>${i}</div>`;
                }
            }


    document.getElementsByClassName("days")[0].innerHTML = cells;

        function dayChanger(obj) {
            obj.classList.add('AddedClass');
            dt.setDate(obj.getAttribute('data-value'));
        }
```

Comment: There's not enough code to try and reproduce you're issue, please edit your question and add all relevant code to [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I edited it, can u help me now?

Comment: Use the Browser's developer tools to inspect the DOM and check if the class `today` is indeed being added.

Comment: no I dont see it there. But if add here console.log(obj.classList), it shows me the class in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector('.today').onclick = function () {
  this.classList.add('todayNew');
}
```

```css
.todayNew {
background-color: #27ae60;
color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="today">Value</div>
```

Comment: "Cannot set property 'onclick' of null"

Comment: old class must be specified in div  <div class="today">Value</div>

Comment: for this query - querySelector('.today')

Comment: cells += `<div class='today' onclick='dayChanger(this);' data-value='${i}'>${i}</div>`;
            
const myDiv = document.querySelector('.today').onclick = function () {
        this.classList.add('todayNew');
    };

Comment: you don`t need 
`onclick='dayChanger(this);`
only
`cells += <div class='today' data-value='${i}'>${i}</div>;` 

This call after adding cells,  
`const myDiv = document.querySelector('.today').onclick = function () { this.classList.add('todayNew'); };`

div with class  today must be in document

Comment: I found the mistake, it was in object which was refreshing the page so i couldnt see the changes >]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simplified and working version of your code

```js
function classAdding(obj) {
  obj.classList.add('today');
}
```

```css
.today {
  background-color: #27ae60;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="classAdding(this)">something</div>
```

Comment: Cant see the difference between your and mine code. Only in the div generator, but I need to do it that way.

Comment: @David you added only partial code with variables that don't exist and without html so it's really hard to know the difference. Please add independent code that simulates your situation and I'll be able to help you :D

Comment: So I have edited it. Is it better now? I can share the whole project, but it will be harder to orientate

Comment: @David it looks like you never add cells to the dom at all

Comment: The code works nice, the cells are displaying normally as I want them. But I just cant give them class onlick. I am adding them there - document.getElementsByClassName("days")[0].innerHTML = cells; - i forgot to edit this row too.